# insert query in MySQL error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have create a function. When the user click the button, data will automatic inset into order table. But it keep give me error. I use the way to do my register page is working fine.

Error Message:
An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order(UserId, OrderStatus, OrderDate) values ('kit', 'Pending', '2014-12-08 22:4' at line 1

```
  If Session("OrderId") Is Nothing Then
        Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = "server = localhost; user id = root; password = root; database = db_fyp"
        Dim com As New MySqlCommand

        conn.Open()
        Dim query As String

        query = "insert into order(UserId, OrderStatus, OrderDate) values (@UserId, @OrderStatus, @OrderDate)"

        com = New MySqlCommand(query, conn)

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Session("Username"))
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderStatus", "Pending")
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderDate", Now())

        com.ExecuteNonQuery()

        conn.Close()
    End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Not sure but Order is a keyword in SQL. Try to put backsticks around that table name. _insert into ``order`` (UserId, OrderStatus, OrderDate) values (@UserId, @OrderStatus, @OrderDate)_

Comment: Confirmed! Order is a Reserved word in Mysql: All reserved words kan be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Uhm no way to put a backstick in a comment?

Comment: Thank you!!! I has been finding the error for whole day.

Answer (score 0):

Order is a reserved keyword in any SQL language known. I really suggest to change that table name to something less problematic. In the meantime you could change the query to

```
query = "insert into `order` (UserId, OrderStatus, OrderDate) " & _
        "values (@UserId, @OrderStatus, @OrderDate)"
```

Comment: Just curious, in MS-SQL you can use square bracket `[objectname]` to distinguish database objects from keywords.  Is that MS specific or is it part of the ANSI standard?

Comment: Really I don't know. I have always take this as an hurdle that every database system throws between you and your database independent code. I am curious as you but I haven't enough time to delve the different SQL Standards [Wikipedia - Sql Standardization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL)